# making text boxes visible

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down if i click it will retrieve values from db.If thre are 4 values that has to pass into text box and make it visible.If 5 values then 5 values has to get visible.There will be a count if 4 boxes count has to get into 5th box.if 5 values then count has to get int0 6th box.
How do i do it?

Comment: huh? do you already have input boxes in the markup? how does the data from the database come to the client? xml? json?

Comment: Exactly what sort of text box?  Do you mean a `<textarea>`? If you used CSS to make it not visible, then you'll need to change the CSS `display` property to `block`.  If you used some other method, then what method?

Answer (score 1):

If the text boxes are in the markup and you've just hidden them (e.g., `style="display: none"`), you can show them again by setting their `style.display` property to `""`:

```
textBoxElement.style.display = "";
```

For example, here's a button click handler that looks for a text field to show and shows it; if there aren't any more to show, it hides the button:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

document.getElementById('btnShowField').onclick = function() {
  var index, field, foundOne, foundMore;

  foundOne = foundMore = false;
  for (index = 0; index < myForm.elements.length; ++index) {
    field = myForm.elements[index];
    if (field.type === "text" && field.style.display === "none") {
      if (!foundOne) {
        // Found one, show it
        field.style.display = "";
        foundOne = true;
      }
      else {
        // Found more, so we don't need to hide the button
        foundMore = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!foundMore) {
    // No more hidden fields, hide the button
    this.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ocuhi4/2)

If you want to add more text boxes to a form at runtime when they aren't in the markup, you can easily do that:

```
var textBox = document.createElement('input');
textBox.type = "text";
textBox.name = "somename";
formElement.appendChild(textBox);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ocuhi4)

Usually the structure will be a bit more complex than that, but that's the general idea.

---

**Off-topic**: A lot of these things can be made dramatically easier by leveraging a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They'll smooth over browser differences and provide a lot of value-add functionality, so you can focus on what you're actually trying to do rather than browser quirks and such.

Comment: @T.JCrowder:already i have text boxe invisible:if 4 values comes from db then four text boxes has to get visible and count should move to 5th box.

Comment: @daffodil: Then that would be the first part, the `style.display` bit. I've added a rough example, but I do strongly recommend a library for this sort of thing.

Comment: J Crowder:where to display values if 2 values then 2 boxes has to get visible then count in 3rd box.I am doing itwith drop down box